# How to compare two different group regression coefficient with feols?(a function from fixest package)

Tags: r, difference, coefficients, fixest

I want to compare weather the effect of x to y are different in male group and female group.
So i hvae run the regress like this.

```
library(arrow)
library(fixest)
df <- arrow::read_feather('test.feather')
res <- feols(y~x | id +year , data = df, split=~gender)
etable(res, ……)
```

the coef of x may shows like this:x 0.251***(gender=0)        0.269***(gender=1).

my questions is : how the check the two coefficents are significant different or not?

Thank you!

1. run the regression like this: feols(y~x*gender | id + year )
2. maybe using the function linearHypothesis from `car` package to test the diffience? but i don't know how.
3. run suest may handle my work.